# malloc puts "garbage" values

Tags: c, malloc, strcat, garbage

how can i prevent or bypass the garbage valus malloc puts in my variable?
attached the code and the output!
thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* hour_char = "13";
    char* day_char = "0";
    char* time = malloc(strlen(hour_char)+strlen(day_char)+2);
    time = strcat(time,day_char);
    time = strcat(time,"-");
    time = strcat(time,hour_char);
    printf("%s",time);
    free(time);
}
```

this is the output i get:

```
á[┼0-13
```

Comment: `malloc` doesn't write to the allocated memory. You need to explicitly initialise the memory yourself. In particular, your code has Undefined Behaviour because you are passing buffer, `time`, that is not a NUL terminated string to `strcat`.

Comment: after `malloc` do `time[0] = 0;` or use `calloc`

Comment: why not use `snprintf `

Comment: Stop using strcat on uninitialized memory?

Comment: If you want your memory to be initialised then consider using `calloc()` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first `strcat` is incorrect, because `malloc`-ed memory is uninitialized. Rather than using `strcat` for the first write, use `strcpy`. It makes sense, because initially `time` does not have a string to which you concatenate anything.

```
time = strcpy(time, day_char);
time = strcat(time, "-");
time = strcat(time, hour_char);
```

Better yet, use `sprintf` or `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(time, sizeof(time), "%s-%s", day_char, hour_char);
```

Comment: Better yet, use `snprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, quoting `C11`, chapter 7.22.3.4 (*emphasis mine*)

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and
>   **whose value is indeterminate.**

So, the content of the memory location is indeterminate. That **is** the expected behaviour.

Then, the problem starts when you use the same pointer as the argument where a *string* is expected, i.e, the first argument of `strcat()`.

Quoting chapter 7.24.3.1 (*again, emphasis mine*)

> The `strcat` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2` (including the
>   terminating null character) to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`. **The initial character
>   of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`.**

but, in your case, there's no guarantee of the *terminating null* in the target, so it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to 0-initialize the memory (or, at least the first element of the memory should be a null) before doing so. You can use `calloc()` which returns a pointer to already 0-initialized memory, or least, do `time[0] = '\0';`.

On a different note, you can also make use of [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) which removes the hassle of initial 0-filling.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` expects to get passed a null-terminated C string. You pass random garbage to it.

This can easily be fixed by turning your data into a null-terminated string of length 0.

```
char* time = malloc(strlen(hour_char)+strlen(day_char)+2);
time[0] = '\0';
time = strcat(time,day_char);
```